# Python PyQt: I could not display the data in lineedit from external program

Tags: python, pyqt

I am trying to display runtime data from EPICS (Package) in lineedit. I can receive and send my data through my program but when I can't display the data. The function pv.get() is giving the data from EPICS to Python. Please suggest me the changes because the SIGNAL function in connect is giving the error

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
import epics
from epics import *

class MyFrame(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
            QWidget.__init__(self)

            self.lineedit = QLineEdit(self)
            self.lineedit.setGeometry(QRect(250,450,75,28))

            pv=epics.PV('calc:sum.VAL')
            self.lineedit=pv.get()

            self.connect(self.lineedit, SIGNAL("textChanged()"), self.changedata)
            self.color = QColor(Qt.blue)

            self.show()

    def changedata (self):

            pv=epics.PV('calc:sum.VAL')
            self.lineedit=pv.get()
            text=pv.get()


            self.update()


app=QApplication(sys.argv)
f=MyFrame()
f.show()
app.exec_()
```

`

Comment: shouldn't you use `self.lineedit.setText(pv.get())` ?

Answer (score 0):

*Credit to @ivica for the suggestion. I saw it was 11 hours with no answer so I thought I would contribute*

You are replacing your `QLineEdit` widget with whatever data your `pv.get()` is returning. What you want to do is actually set the data onto the widget.

```
class MyFrame(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.lineedit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.lineedit.setGeometry(QRect(250,450,75,28))

        pv=epics.PV('calc:sum.VAL')
        self.lineedit.setText(pv.get())

        # new-style signal slot connections
        self.lineedit.textChanged.connect(self.changedata)
        self.color = QColor(Qt.blue)


    def changedata (self):

        pv=epics.PV('calc:sum.VAL')
        self.lineedit.setText(pv.get())
```

**Update**

Examining your code example more closely I see some more potential issues.

Though I am using the new style signal connections, in your old style you are missing the proper signature:

```
self.connect(self.lineedit, SIGNAL("textChanged()"), self.changedata)
# should be
self.connect(self.lineedit, SIGNAL("textChanged(QString)"), self.changedata)
```

Now, that being said... I don't understand why you would connect the changing of the text field to a slot that then changes the text field. It will cause a couple recursive triggers. If what you are trying to do is catch the editing of the text, and instead call your epics lib and set the text from that, then you should be using the `textEdited` signal which will not be emitted when you programmatically change the field.

```
# new style
self.lineedit. textEdited.connect(self.changedata)
# old style
self.connect(self.lineedit, SIGNAL("textEdited(QString)"), self.changedata)
```

Comment: Thanks ivica and @jdi, I have already used this combination but I can't get the updated value in lineedit. I only get the updated value when I restart my program. Actualy, I want to update the runtime value in lineedt 'pv2=epics.PV('calc:sum.VAL')
        self.lineedit.setText(str(pv2.get())) self.connect(self.lineedit,SIGNAL("textChanged(QString)"),self.changedata)    def changedata(self):
            pv2=epics.PV('calc:sum.VAL')
            self.lineedit1.setText(str(pv2.get()))
            self.update()'

Comment: I don't know why you wouldn't be seeing a change of text when the `setText` is called. Is your epics library blocking or something? Have you tried simply using string values as a test, without the epics.PV to make sure you can set strings? Something isn't right

Comment: I got a strange behavior in lineedit, I can get the updated data only when I move my cursor in the lineedit and press any key then I get the updated data. I feel that program is waiting for some other thing command to work. Any suggestion/comment to solve this problem

Comment: You are doing something somewhere to block the event loop, or maybe you didnt even start the event loop. Not sure unless I see more or all of the code. Your UI should be updating changes right away.

Comment: your code above is a complete code. I am running python and pyqt4 on fedora.

Comment: I have added some more information about what might be another problem for you

Comment: thanks a lot for your response. I have already used the SIGNAL("textEdited(QString)") but the problem is same. I came to conclusion that problem is not in the python or pyqt, I feel this is the problem of linux. The reason I can get the updated value in my lineedit only if I press any key of the keyboard. So, if by some way I can disable the keyboard during runtime then then I can get the updated data  without any disturbance. Any suggestion about this.

Comment: I still have no idea what this means, not updating unless a keypress. How else would it update? You are using a signal that reacts to editing the text field. Can you explain a 1.2.3 process of what you are doing and what is not working.  For something obscure like this, I wouldnt know what to suggest.

Comment: I have posted this question in a better and easy way with title "Python Pyqt: could not display data in lineedit and print command in terminal window"

Comment: I realize that you are new to the site, but in the future it would be better if you had just edited this question to clarify instead of making a new version of the same question and having people start over with it. This question is now of no use and can probably be deleted.

Comment: sure i m new to the site and hopefully will be regular user of it. Thanks for guiding me. I will be happy if this question will be removed.